# Shuffling an ordered list with a given degree of randomness

Tags: probability, statistics, reference-request, algorithms, algorithmic-randomness

I feel like the following problem should have a well-known answer, but unfortunately I don't know the keywords to look up.

I would like a procedure that takes as an input an ordered list of items, and outputs a shuffled version of that list. The procedure should have a tunable 'knob' that determines the degree of randomness (defined in some appropriate sense) in the output list. In particular:

- If the knob is set to 0, the output should be identical to the input
- If the knob is set to 1, the I output should be a complete shuffle, such that none of the input order is preserved (in expectation)
- A small value of the knob should make items likely to move around by a few places up or down the list, but big jumps should be rare

Is there a way to make these ideas precise, and is there a known procedure for this problem?

Any leads would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

One approach could be to give each element a random value which is close to its original position when the knob is close to $0$ and which is almost uniformly distributed when the knob is close to $1$, and then order the output by these random values

For example this is an R function

```
shuffle <- function(x, knob=1){
  if(knob <= 0) {return(x)}
  if(knob >= 1) {knob <- 1}
  n <- length(x)
  a <- 1 + ((1:n)-1)/(n-1) * (1/knob-1)
  b <- 1 + (n-(1:n))/(n-1) * (1/knob-1)
  x[order(rbeta(n,a,b))]
  }
```

which applied to the first half of the alphabet with the knob set to $1,0.2,0.02$ might give

```
> set.seed(2018)
> shuffle(LETTERS[1:13], knob=1)
 [1] "G" "E" "H" "M" "J" "D" "C" "F" "A" "I" "K" "L" "B"
> shuffle(LETTERS[1:13], knob=0.2)
 [1] "C" "B" "E" "A" "J" "D" "F" "H" "I" "M" "G" "L" "K"
> shuffle(LETTERS[1:13], knob=0.02)
 [1] "A" "B" "D" "C" "F" "E" "H" "G" "J" "I" "K" "L" "M"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a quantity called *Kendall's tau*, which would be close to what you want. It is defined more generally but specifically, for two permutations, the Kendall tau distance between them is the *number of pairs that are in different order in the two permutations*.

For example, the Kendall tau distance between $\pi=(0 3 1 6 2 5 4)$ and 
$\sigma=(1 0 3 6 4 2 5)$ is four because the pairs $0-1, 3-1, 2-4, 5-4$ are in different order in the two rankings, but all other pairs are in the same order.

One way of defining the distance is to write
$$
K(\pi,\sigma)=\sum_{\{i,j\}\in P} \mathbf{1}\left\{i ~and~ j~are~in~opposite~order~in~\pi~and~\sigma\right\},
$$
where the sum is over $P,$ the unordered pairs of distinct elements.

This distance is $0$ if the two permutations are the same and $n(n-1)/2$ if they are opposite ordered.

Given a permutation $\pi$, and a value $r\geq 0$ for the Kendall tau, one can generate a permutation $\sigma$ such that $K(\pi,\sigma)=r:$

Let $\sigma=\pi,$ and if $r=0,$ stop output $\sigma.$

Otherwise choose uniformly at random $r$ positions $I_r$ such that $$I_r=\{i_1,\ldots,i_r\} \subset \{0,\ldots,n-1\},$$ and uniformly at random $r$ positions $J_r$ from the remaining positions such that $$J_r=\{j_1,\ldots,j_r\} \subset \{0,\ldots,n-1\} \setminus I_r.$$

For $k=1,\ldots,r,$ let $TEMP:=\sigma(i_r),$ $\sigma(i_r)=\pi(j_r),$ and $\pi(j_r)=TEMP.$